# How to grab a photo or graphic

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have InDesign CS 6. When I try to move photos, or even resize them, the pictures moves inside the frame, or it cuts part of the photo. Is there a shortcut that grabs the entire image--and stays grabbed while I do stuff?

Comment: I was pretty confused at first, but I think what you want is `Cmd`. If you hold down `Cmd` and drag resize a frame, it'll resize the image inside as well. Maybe that is what you want. You could also enable `Auto-fit` in `Object > Fitting > Frame fitting options`. You can also find that in the `Control panel`.

Answer (score 1):

In InDesign, every placed photo goes inside an 'invisible' frame and there is no exception from this. Now, you can either **move the photo inside the frame** with the 'Direct Selection Tool' (shortcut <kbd>A</kbd>) or **move the frame including the photo** with the normal 'Selection Tool' (shortcut <kbd>V</kbd>). I know this can be confusing when starting out with InDesign, but it is the way it works. Further read:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/selecting-objects.html
- https://youtu.be/X_nbrE5LyeY

Answer (score 0):

[image]

STEP 1
Draw the image frame - Shortcut - F

STEP 2
Select the frame and 
Use Control + D on PC to import image

STEP 3
Select the frame and 
Use Contrl + Shift + Alt + E  - fit the image to its propotion
Use Contrl + Shift + Alt + C - Fit the image to the frame
In The top Select AUTO FIT - and transform the frame - so the image is scaled accordingly

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to click on the corner of the photo with the selection tool, and not in the center. If you don't click on the center of the picture and the hand icon appears, do you still move the picture within the frame?